# MVC form not posting when using document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC project and in one view i have to fill a form and post it. I was able to do that, but when I wanted to add masking to a textbox, I used `document.ready` function and it caused the submit button not to react to anything. Without that `document.ready`, the function is working all right. (But it doesn't include the masking, of course.) I looked at several solutions but couldn't get any result. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
@model Models.model

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#txtPhone").mask("0(999) 999-99-99");
});

function disableSubmitButton() {

    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").value = "Wait";

};

</script>

<div id="dvAjax">
@if (Model.SomeList!= null)
{

    using (Ajax.BeginForm("View", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divdiv", HttpMethod = "Post", OnBegin = "disableSubmitButton()" }, new { id = "frmfrm", name = "frmfrm" }))
    {

            <p>
                Your phone: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.phone, new { maxlength = 10, size = 10, id = "txtPhone" })


                <input id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="someClass"
                       value="Cont." />
            </p>
    }

}
</div>
```

and the controller:

```
public ActionResult View(Model model, string btnSubmit)
{
   //some code

   return PartialView("View", model);
}
```

this is how i include jquery and mask files:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js"
                    ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js", 
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-collapse.js", 
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-modal.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-dropdown.js"));

.......
```

Comment: do you have errors in console ?

Comment: Tip: Any special reason to mix up `jQuery` and `Vanilla Javascript` in your code? Choose one way and stick to it.

Comment: @sabotero no i don't have any errors. it just stays still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so at last, i changed the plugin i used for masking and managed.
the first one was conflicting somehow and didn't work with form posting. i don't know. it was that: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

then i tried this and it worked: http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Input-Field-Data-Formatting-Plugin-Mask.html

thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

For ajax loaded content you must use

```
$(document).ajaxComplete( function() { 
 ...
} );
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready( ... )
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) the documentation.

Comment: hi. when i make it (document).ajaxComplete i cannot see the mask on textbox but after i clicked the submit button it appears. and actually it was working before in that way. please see my comment on the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your script in the `@section scripts` placeholder defined in your `Shared/_Layout` view.

My guess is jQuery is not charged at this point.
I would expect an error.

Also verify that `mask` is actualy a function. Are you using a plugin? the plugin is inlcuded? After jquery?

Try this :

```
@model Models.model
@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $("#txtPhone").mask("0(999) 999-99-99");
});

function disableSubmitButton() {

    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").value = "Wait";

};

</script>
}
<div id="dvAjax">
@if (Model.SomeList!= null)
{

    using (Ajax.BeginForm("View", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divdiv", HttpMethod = "Post", OnBegin = "disableSubmitButton()" }, new { id = "frmfrm", name = "frmfrm" }))
    {

            <p>
                Your phone: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.phone, new { maxlength = 10, size = 10, id = "txtPhone" })


                <input id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="someClass"
                       value="Cont." />
            </p>
    }

}
</div>
```

Comment: Would you mind putting some kind of explanation? Answers like _try this_ are not very welcome here.

Comment: hi. yes mask is actually a function and when that view loads i can see this mask on the text box. i had such an interesting problem: 

1st scenario: when i first don't fill that box and click the button it posts the form and gives an error like "enter your number" and then when i enter the number and click the button it post the form, it was ok. 

2nd scenario: when the view loads for the first time and i enter the number correctly and then click the submit button it don't react.

Comment: How are you including jquery and the plugin for the mask? Also could you provide more code to see more deeper

Comment: @sabotero actually this is the whole code that should be working. and i include jquery and mask plugin via bundleconfig.cs that i add some part of it to the question now.

Comment: also these have the same result too.
window.onload = function () { $("#txtPhone").mask("0(999) 999-99-99"); };
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        $("#txtPhone").mask("0(999) 999-99-99");
    });